# Boot stuck after journal recovery

Tags: boot, nvidia, 22.04, acer, ubuntu-gnome

```
[0.105662] x86/cpu: VMX (outside TXT) disabled by BIOS
[0.105666] x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.
[0.761716] integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65
[0.761731] integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65
/dev/nvme0n1p2: recovering journal
/dev/nvme0n1p2: clean, 486177/15597568 files, 14041716/62383360 blocks
[2.785442]
```

My laptop frequently halts at this message when booting/restarting. This issue has only been occasional in the past, though it has arrived to the point where I cannot boot at all. I'm extremely new to Ubuntu, and Linux as a whole, and I genuinely have no idea what the cause of this is (sorry if everything I'm saying makes 0 sense). I've gone through various threads, trying to address the initial logging statements. I've read that the certificate warning is potentially caused by secure and fast boot being enabled in the BIOS, though this issue still persists despite those being disabled. Additionally, I've tried addressing the journal recovery statement by going into root recovery mode and executing `sudo fsck -f /` to no avail. (I have literally no idea what I'm doing) I'm running on Ubuntu 22.04 with the default Ubuntu GNOME desktop environment.

Boot logging statements:

[image: boot logging statements]

Comment: Ignore the first 2 they are information messages not errors. The recovering journal means the machine was not shut down properly, like you used the power switch. You can read the contents of that file for some hints on what may have gone wrong. The last one is again an information message and you can ignore it or search this site for how to make it go away. I do not know what is causing the x.509 but search this site and see what you find.